# HTML5 and CSS3 navigation bar hover

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

Everyone, I'm still a beginner at HTML5 and CSS3

I wish to have the effect like this. 
And I tried many time and I failed to achieved. 
The main

still remain the colour although the mouse move to it's child.

[image: Navigation Sample]

The CSS code should look like?

HTML 5 code as requested.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery Navigation menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="no-js">
    <nav id="topNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">SERVICES</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 1">Sub Nav Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 2">Sub Nav Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 3">Sub Nav Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 4">Sub Nav Link 4</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 5">Sub Nav Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>        
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">ENQUITIES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>      
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."<p>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

while here is the CSS3

```
/* JS disabled styles */
.no-js nav li:hover ul 
{ 
    display:block; 
}

/* base nav styles */
nav 
{
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 16px Tahoma, Sans-serif;
}

/*Temporaly Solution*/
nav ul a 
{ 
   border-bottom: thin; 
   border-bottom-style: solid;      
   border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
/*Solution Ended*/

nav ul 
{ 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
}

nav li 
{ 
    position:relative; 
    float:left; 
    list-style-type:none; 
}

nav ul:after 
{ 
    content:"."; 
    display:block; 
    height:0; 
    clear:both; 
    visibility:hidden; 
}

nav ul a:hover 
{ 
    color: #F90; 
}

nav li a 
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}

nav li a:focus 
{ 
    outline:none; 
    text-decoration:underline; 
}

nav li:first-child a 
{ 
    border-left:none; 
}

nav li.last a 
{ 
    border-right:none; 
}

nav a span 
{ 
    display:block; 
    float:right; 
    margin-left:5px; 
}

nav ul ul 
{ 
    display:none; 
    width:110%; 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    background:#FFFFFF; 
}

nav ul ul li 
{ 
    float:none; 
}

nav ul ul a 
{ 
    padding:5px 10px; 
    border-left:none; 
    border-right:none; 
    font-size:14px; 
}

/* CSS3 */

    .cssgradients nav li:hover { background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 100px 90deg, #999, #222); background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#222), to(#555)); }
    .borderradius nav ul ul { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px; border-bottom-left-radius:4px; border-bottom-right-radius:4px; }
    .boxshadow.rgba nav ul ul {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    }
    .rgba nav ul ul li { border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
    .rgba nav ul ul a:hover {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    }
    .borderradius.rgba nav ul ul li.last { border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px; border-bottom-left-radius:4px; border-bottom-right-radius:4px; }
    .csstransforms ul a span { -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg); }
```

Comment: It will easy for us to continue with your code.

Comment: @Dev
OK. I try include it. Anyway nothing much from there since I just starting to figure out how it works ><

Comment: @VladimirKadalashvili
Erm. I still a beginner for this. So nothing much. Just found it unable to remain the color when i hover to its child and I have no idea how to make it remain there ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `:hover` pseudo-class to the parent li tag.

```
nav ul li:hover > a 
{ 
    color: #F90; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edwin. 
Erm. I tried. But it enlighten all of the <li> within the item

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I missed `>` after `hover`.

Comment: o Yeah. Thank Edwin. 
U saved my world. Haha. 
Any good reference i can learn about this? 
I trying to make HTML 5 and CSS3 nearly ><

Comment: Your best reference would be google. Try to search for everything you don't know and be sure someone has already answered it, and if not there is always StackOverflow.

Comment: Erm. Actually i tried to search google. 
The problem is I have no idea how to search it. 
Dun have the keyword to accomplish this. Haha

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/* JS disabled styles */
.no-js nav li:hover ul 
{ 
    display:block; 
}

/* base nav styles */
nav 
{
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 16px Tahoma, Sans-serif;
}

/*Temporaly Solution*/
nav ul a 
{ 
   border-bottom: thin; 
   border-bottom-style: solid;      
   border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
/*Solution Ended*/

nav ul 
{ 
    padding:0; 
    margin:0; 
}

nav li 
{ 
    position:relative; 
    float:left; 
    list-style-type:none; 
}

nav ul:after 
{ 
    content:"."; 
    display:block; 
    height:0; 
    clear:both; 
    visibility:hidden; 
}

nav ul a:hover, nav ul > li:hover > a 
{ 
    color: #F90; 
}

nav li a 
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}

nav li a:focus 
{ 
    outline:none; 
    text-decoration:underline; 
}

nav li:first-child a 
{ 
    border-left:none; 
}

nav li.last a 
{ 
    border-right:none; 
}

nav a span 
{ 
    display:block; 
    float:right; 
    margin-left:5px; 
}

nav ul ul 
{ 
    display:none; 
    width:110%; 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    background:#FFFFFF; 
}

nav ul ul li 
{ 
    float:none; 
}

nav ul ul a 
{ 
    padding:5px 10px; 
    border-left:none; 
    border-right:none; 
    font-size:14px; 
}

/* CSS3 */

    .cssgradients nav li:hover { background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 100px 90deg, #999, #222); background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#222), to(#555)); }
    .borderradius nav ul ul { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px; border-bottom-left-radius:4px; border-bottom-right-radius:4px; }
    .boxshadow.rgba nav ul ul {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    }
    .rgba nav ul ul li { border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
    .rgba nav ul ul a:hover {
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    }
    .borderradius.rgba nav ul ul li.last { border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px; border-bottom-left-radius:4px; border-bottom-right-radius:4px; }
    .csstransforms ul a span { -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg); }
```

Hope that works.

Comment: Erm. Thanks for helping. 
It not really working. When hover, all of the li lighten up. Haha

Comment: A link about? U mean the sample website or?

Answer (score 1):

That will add the color to all link elements. To add only to the first link element replace:

```
nav ul a:hover 
{ 
    color: #F90; 
}
```

by

```
nav ul a:hover, nav ul > li:hover > a 
{ 
    color: #F90; 
}
```

This way works. Already tried it locally.